# Gaussian Mixture Model $p(x_i | z_i = k)$ a likelihood or probability?

Tags: continuous-data, gaussian-mixture-distribution, marginal-distribution

In Gaussian Mixture models, the probability of observing the data $x$ given that it was generated from $M$ gaussian models is given by the following equation $$p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m p(x|z=k)p(z = k)$$

People usually refer $p(x|z=k)$ as the probability that gaussian $k$ generated the data $x$ and replaces it with the gaussian density function $N(\mu_k,\Sigma_k)$. However, $N(\mu_k,\sigma_k)$ is the pdf of the gaussian which represents the likelihood of observing $x$ rather than a probability since for continuous distributions the probability for a single data point is 0 although the likelihood is proportional to the probability. Is it considered a probability or a likelihood ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Gaussian mixture, the functions $p(x)$ and $p(x|Z=k)$ are probability densities, not probability mass functions. In case the mixture model has parameters $\theta$ like $\mu_k$ and $\sigma_k$, the likelihood function is the product of the $ p_\theta(x_i)$'s
$$\ell(\theta) =\prod_{i=1}^n p_\theta(x_i)\tag{1}$$
seen as a function of $\theta$ for a given sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where, e.g.,
$$p_\theta(x_i) = \sum_{k=1}^m \mathbb P(Z_i = k) p(x_i | \mu_k,\sigma_k)$$
Formally, the case $n=1$ makes $p_\theta(x_1)$ a likelihood as well, although estimating $\theta$ from a single observation is of little interest.

Comment: the y-axis of the probability densities is essentially the likelihood of observing x ? is $p_{\theta}(x_i)  = \sum_{k=1}^m p(z_i = k) p(x_i | \mu_k,\sigma_k)$

Comment: How would we interpret $p(x)$ in terms of a probability density function ? Since $x$ is a given data point and not a random variable

Comment: I am not certain we are discussing the same objects. For me, likelihood means the likelihood function $\ell(\theta)$, introduced by R.A. Fisher, that is used in estimation by maximum likelihood. It is defined as (1) in my answer. It is equal to the density (1) of the sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ at the realised sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.